# SQL Format Date User Defined Function Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a user defined function that looks like this;

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func_format_date]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @input VARCHAR(6)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @mon CHAR(2),
        @day char(2),
        @year char(4),
        @output DATETIME
 
    -- Return the result of the function
    SELECT @mon = LEFT(@input, 2), @day =SUBSTRING(@input, 3,2), @year = RIGHT(@input,4)
 
    SELECT @output = @year+@mon+@day
 
    RETURN CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @output, 12)
END
```

The goal is to be able to pass in a date say `“022019”` (mmddyy) and the function will format the date as such `“190220”` (yymmdd). This seems to work only sometime as if I pass in the following dates see the results below; it seems to be inconsistent in terms of the dates it accepts vs the dates that throw an error

1. `022019` (Works fine)
2. `032019` (Works fine)
3. `021019` (Results in a “The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.” error)
4. `030519` (Results in a “The conversion of a varchar data type to a
   datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.” error)

I have checked to ensure the default language is correct and it is. Can someone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Question your Year in your function is doing 4 digits, but your only passing 2 in the input?

Comment: What is 2 + 2 + 4? You defined your parameter as varchar(6). See any issues?

Comment: Almost 20 years after Y2K - no one should be using or accepting 2 digit years. NO ONE!

Comment: I tested and saw error, test your code without being in function, and change your output to varchar for testing so you can see what you will get from results.  This way it wont error out, but will send you specific output, and you can see what is happening

Comment: Any chance of leading/trailing spaces/characters in the sting?

Comment: Dates are binary values. They have no format. There's no `mmddyy` or `yymmdd` date, they are just dates. What's the point of this function? Why not just uses `PARSE` to parse whatever format is there into a date?

Comment: As for the error, it's precisely because dates have no format. `SELECT @output = @year+@mon+@day` has to parse the date using the *current culture*. `YYMMDD` is just another string. The unambiguous date literal is `YYYYMMDD` or the full ISO8601 format

Comment: And yes, two-digit years are just begging for trouble and bad data. There are a *lot* of people alive whose birth dates can't be handled this way

Comment: @SMor I wish I had a choice but the files we receive only have two digit years.

Comment: Don't parse the data with SQL, clean them up *before* you enter the data into the database. `DateTime.ParseExact` in C# for example would have no trouble parsing this string. SQL Server has nothing similar. And returning a *string* from that function is simply wrong. It means there's *another* chance of getting bad data now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason for this error - your `@input` parameter is `varchar(6)`, you read `1st` and `2nd` characters as month, `3rd` and `4th` as day, and `3rd`, `4th`, `5th` and `6th` as year. When `@input` is equal to '021019', your year will be `1019` and this is outside the `datetime` [datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) range.

Second, change your logic:

- make your `@input` parameter varchar(8)
- generate `datetime` value using [DATETIMEFROMPARTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function if you have four digit year

If you want to fix your function, next may help:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func_format_date]
(
   @input VARCHAR(6)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
   -- Declare the return variable here
   DECLARE 
      @mon VARCHAR(2),
      @day VARCHAR(2),
      @year VARCHAR(2),
      @output DATETIME

   -- Return the result of the function
   SELECT 
      @mon = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, 2), 
      @day = SUBSTRING(@input, 3, 2), 
      @year = SUBSTRING(@input, 5, 2)

   -- Generate datetime value
   SELECT @output = CONVERT(datetime, @year + @mon + @day, 12)
   -- or if your dates are after 2000 
   --SELECT @output = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2000 + @year, @mon, @day, 0, 0, 0, 0)

   -- Return value
   RETURN CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @output, 12)
END
```

Comment: Assuming 2000 for a base year is wrong. That would convert 99 to 2099. SQL Server's [configurable cutoff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) is 2049.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right, `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` is usefull with four digit years and it's not sure that dates will be after 2000. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Simply your function using below Stmt.

1. If no Date Validation Required you can interchange values.
   select RIGHT(@input,2) + LEFT(@input, 2) + SUBSTRING(@input, 3,2)
2. If Date Validation Required use below.
   select Convert(varchar, Convert(datetime, LEFT(@input, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@input, 3,2) + '/' + RIGHT(@input,2), 1), 12)